# Get last month index from sql output in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$SQL = "SELECT value FROM shpb_control WHERE control_id='bulan'";
$Q = $obj->db->query($SQL);

$month_now=$Q->row()->value;
```

For example, `$month_now='02'`

What is the function in PHP, to get the last `month = '01'` ?

example:

`$month_now = '02'`, and `$month_previous = '01'`

Thank You.

Comment: `date('m', strtotime('-1 month'));`. See [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime)

Comment: But, the value of month_now is not always same with date('m'), it depends on the output of the SQL.. Thanks..

Comment: I though you meant "month now" like this month. `date('m', strtotime($month_now.' -1 month'));`

Comment: @Mihai lorga. Perfect and briliant, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
date('m', strtotime($month_now.' -1 month'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MONTH` function available in mysql and `strtotime` function in php.

**PHP**

```
echo date('m', strtotime(date('m')." -1 month"));
```

**MySQL**

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE MONTH(date_field) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: But, the value of month_now is not always same with date('m'), it depends on the output of the SQL.. Thanks..

Comment: @beben it does not matter you can also use date function if value comes from DB..